# ios Core data bug with predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have some strange behaviour with my Core Data.

I have entity `Card`, that have `NSNumber` property `idObject`

When I want to change some info in this card, I try find similar card in my CoreData, but sometimes it work, and sometimes not. I mean next:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Card"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idObject == %@", objectId];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [self.backgroundManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Sometimes this code return objects array, but sometimes it return nil. I add next code after previous part of code:

```
request.predicate = nil;
NSArray *cards = [self.backgroundManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Error always nil, so all must be fine.
And `cards` array has `Card` with `idObject`, that I try to find. So finally if we try execute next code several times:

```
NSLog(@"idObject -%@-", objectId);
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Card"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idObject == %@", objectId];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [self.backgroundManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"objects count = %i", objects.count);
request.predicate = nil;
NSArray *cards = [self.backgroundManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSLog(@"\nCards:");
for (Card *card in cards) {
    NSLog(@"id -%@-", card.idObject);
}
```

So we have next results. In first time you can see next:

```
2014-03-10 11:58:47.115[4397:6613] idObject -1-
2014-03-10 11:58:47.127[4397:6613] objects count = 1
2014-03-10 11:58:47.134[4397:6613] 
Cards:
2014-03-10 11:58:47.145[4397:6613] id -5-
2014-03-10 11:58:47.146[4397:6613] id -4-
2014-03-10 11:58:47.148[4397:6613] id -1-
2014-03-10 11:58:47.148[4397:6613] id -2-
2014-03-10 11:58:47.149[4397:6613] id -6-
2014-03-10 11:58:47.150[4397:6613] id -8-
2014-03-10 11:58:47.151[4397:6613] id -7-
2014-03-10 11:58:47.152[4397:6613] id -3-
```

In second it return me:

```
2014-03-10 11:59:42.752[4397:9e2b] idObject -1-
2014-03-10 11:59:42.758[4397:9e2b] objects count = 0
2014-03-10 11:59:42.761[4397:9e2b] 
Cards:
2014-03-10 11:59:42.762[4397:9e2b] id -1-
2014-03-10 11:59:42.764[4397:9e2b] id -5-
2014-03-10 11:59:42.766[4397:9e2b] id -2-
2014-03-10 11:59:42.768[4397:9e2b] id -6-
2014-03-10 11:59:42.769[4397:9e2b] id -8-
2014-03-10 11:59:42.771[4397:9e2b] id -3-
2014-03-10 11:59:42.773[4397:9e2b] id -4-
2014-03-10 11:59:42.775[4397:9e2b] id -7-
```

So I have in `cards` array always `Card` with such `idObject`, but why with my predicate, it sometimes return me that card and sometimes no? What's wrong?

Comment: what is the type of `objectId` in predicate?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr, shit I'm so noobie =( That's right, I use in predicate NSString, but in property I have NSNumber. Thank you, write your answer, and I vote it like right answer, Thanks a lot

Comment: from the documentation the only time that executeFetchRequest returns nil is when an error occurs, so log the error and it should say what has gone wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Card` entity property `idObject` is type of `NSNumber`, change `idObject` in predicate to `NSNumber`
ie.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idObject == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[idObject integerValue]]];
```

or use `NSNumberFormatter` to change `idObject` to `NSNumber`.

Hope this will help you